# how to exclude a string if it's in a URL using regex?

Tags: regex

I'm replacing a number of different strings, but only want them to replace in normal text, and not get rewritten when they appear as a link in a document. The regex to find the strings is very straightforward: `/word|anotherword|athirdword/gi` but what that means is that if there's a link that contains `anotherword`it's getting found and then replaced as well, breaking the link.

I think I just need a part in my regex that says "but just ignore anything that starts with http or https" but not sure how to write that.

thanks so much!

edit. here's what I'm doing with the javascript

```
if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var text = node.nodeValue;
        var replacedText = text.replace(/word|anotherword|athirdword/gi, 'replaced text');

        if (replacedText !== text) {
            element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
        }
    }
```

the result replaces those three strings anywhere on a page, which is great. except it changes `http://www.foo.com/the-whole-world` into `http://www.foo.com/the-whole-replaced text` which obviously breaks the link.

Comment: Could you please add, which regex flavour you are using and some sample data (input, output)

Comment: I gotta say, I'm not sure what you mean by "flavor"

Comment: There are a lot of different versions of regex, depending what language or tool you are using, so this information is rather important for a correct answer

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'm doing this in Javascript.

Comment: expanded the original query for clarity.

Comment: What's the normal text look like? Do you mean some texts start with 'http(s)', the others are normal without  'http(s)'? An example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I would try negative lookbehind.

Negative lookbehind differs greatly from flavor to flavor, so it won't work in different flavors.

For JavaScript, you can try following:

```
str.replace(/(http:[\/\.-a-z0-9]+)?(word|anotherword|athirdword)/gi, function($0, $1){
 return $1 ? $0 : '';
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egwtw25z/).

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string first, then do a conditional replace:

```js
function condReplace(str) {
  var sentences = [];
  var res = str.split(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)(?:\s+|$)/i);
  res.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry) {
      if (entry.match(/^http?:\/\//i)) {
        sentences.push(entry);
      } else {
        sentences.push(entry.replace(/word|anotherword|athirdword/g, "REPLACED"))
      }
    }
  });
  document.write(sentences.join(" "));
}

var str = "http://sometext.com/word.doc and This is a word normal text anotherword containing a anotherword another link http://www.foo.com/the-whole-word. This is a single word.";
condReplace(str);
```